# Amazon web service (Pay Fort) payment integrated with spring

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, payfort

i will used Custom merchant page technique by Pay Fort with spring boot
i need know how i can make simple payment method by Amazon payment services (Pay Fort) in sequence workflow

like check the credit card
and Deduction of money from the card if verify card

i  read the Pay Fort document but is very ambiguous and dont has document for do payment from the system

this is Pay Fort document  https://paymentservices-reference.payfort.com/docs/api/build/index.html?java#before-starting-your-integration-follow-these-steps

Comment: your pay front document's link is incorrect

Comment: thanks i updated https://paymentservices-reference.payfort.com/docs/api/build/index.html?java#before-starting-your-integration-follow-these-steps and this is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must call payfort technical and select success channel with set true configuration after that